# Rodar teste automatizado no Test manager

Tags: testes-automatizados

Criei um plano de test automatizado no test manager e defini a build no Team Project, mas ao rodar pelo Test manager em Run with, apresenta o seguinte erro:

> "The build directory of the test run either does not exist or access permission is required."

É necessário criar uma máquina para rodar a aplicação?

Comment: Ele está falando que a configuração não está boa. O diretório é inacessível, seja por permissão ou por inexistência. Como está a configuração do teste? Em que tipo de máquina está instalado o `test manager`?